# Docker swarm replica stays 0/1 and service stays in status new

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have a problem with my docker swarm. I created a new service with the following command:

```
docker-compose config | docker stack deploy -c - serviceNameX --with-registry-auth
```

The docker-compose file looks like that:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  serviceNameX:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}imageNameX:${VERSION}
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 2gb
    env_file:
      - ../common.env
      - .env

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: ${DOCKER_NETWORK}
```

fyi: docker-compose config is used because docker stack deploy can't expand environment variables. At least to my knowledge.

docker service ps serviceNameX

```
ID                  NAME                              IMAGE                                                         NODE                DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE       ERROR               PORTS
ify7vhl0l2m8        serviceNameX.1   nexus.local/imageNameX:1                                                                           Running             New 2 hours ago
```

docker service ls

```
afnjo97f6nuf        serviceNameX                      replicated          0/1                 nexus.local/imageNameX:1
```

All nodes are Ready and Active

There is no indication or information of an error. Usually docker service ps shows if an error occurs. Is there another useful log?

Comment: Other useful tools could be `docker events`, `docker service inspect`, and `docker container inspect` (on that ify7vhl0l2m8).  I'd also do a `watch docker service ps serviceNameX` to see if tasks were re-spawing but indeed it's weird to see a single task "running" but a 0/1 in service ls.

Comment: The output was a little bit displaced, but actually the desired state is RUNNING and the actual state is NEW

Answer (score 2):

Try do pull your image manually first.

```
docker pull ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}imageNameX:${VERSION}
```

And then re-run your compose-file

It may be a bug using a private registry, or something simple as you don't have enough disk space to pull the image.